# CORS settings not being applied to Azure Function?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-functions

While testing the API definition of my Azure Function (within the portal) I get this CORS error:

> This is a cross-origin call. Make sure the server at ***.azurewebsites.net accepts POST requests from functions.azure.com. Learn more

I verified that this is listed as a CORS allowed origin within the function settings:

> https://functions.azure.com

[image]
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the API definition. CORS was working fine although that was indicated as the problem in the error messages. The missing piece in the API definition was

```
security: []
```

which was missing in the POST section. I guess the security entry is required even if it's empty. It would've been nice if there was a warning that this was missing.

Comment: Where exactly was this supposed to go?

Comment: It's in the OpenAPI (Swagger) definition of the Function app. If you click generate api definition template it'll generate one automatically which includes the security value. For some reason mine was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this on my side.

I added the following to **ALLOWED ORIGINS**:

[image]

The output in the Azure portal:

[image]

I also test it by making a POST request to the function in the browser via jQuery:

[image]

If you want us to dive into this problem you may need to provide detailed steps to reproduce.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but when I try to use my function with the function connector in logic apps, I get this error message: 
Failed to fetch swagger with error message: Failed to fetch. Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint and are calling a valid HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: I think this may be a problem with the API definition, not CORS. I'll report back my findings, thanks.